# Installing two apps but second app gets first app name appended on browse for directory

Tags: nsis

Please note that I initially created an installer for two applications based on https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Two_installations_in_one_installer where the first application is the main one while the second application is the license manager.  That said, I did remove the nested checkboxes with only one layer of checkboxes.  FYI, I have also been referencing this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24187/Creating-an-Installer?msg=5782957#xx5782957xx

The issue that I am having is that when I get to the second license manager app, where I click to browse for a custom folder, and create a new custom folder, when I press OK on the browse it then returns with this custom folder but then appends the application name after that.  So for example when I return from the browse for custom directory dialog, it would not return with, say:

```
C:\Tools\FlexLM
```

It would instead return with the following even though I didn't add the "MyApp" portion:

```
C:\Tools\FlexLM\MyApp
```

Please find the full source code here:

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "Sections.nsh"
    
;Include Modern UI
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define MAJOR_VERSION "1" 
!define MINOR_VERSION "2" 
!define PATCH_VERSION "3" 
!define BUILD_VERSION "4" 
    
!define APP_COPYRIGHT "MyApp © MyCompany 2021"
!define COMPANY_NAME "MyCompany"
!define FLEX_LM "FlexLM"        
!define FLEX_DIR "FlexSQI"            
!define LANG_ENGLSH "English" 
!define PRODUCT_NAME "MyApp"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "${MAJOR_VERSION}.${MINOR_VERSION}.${PATCH_VERSION}.${BUILD_VERSION}"
!define SETUP_NAME "MyAppSetup.exe"

BrandingText "MyCompany"

OutFile ${SETUP_NAME}
Name "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"

InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "Software\$PRODUCT_NAME" ""
ShowInstDetails hide
ShowUnInstDetails hide

SetCompressor /SOLID lzma
SetCompressorDictSize 12

Var MyAppCheckboxState
Var FlexLmCheckboxState

;Request application privileges for Windows 
RequestExecutionLevel admin

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "MyAppLicense.txt"

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesCheck
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE ComponentsLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS   
 
## This is the title on the MyApp Directory page
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_A)"
 
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesA
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
 
## This is the title on the FlexLM Directory page
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_B)"
 
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesB
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE DeleteSectionsINI
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

;--------------------------------
;Languages

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

;--------------------------------

LangString NoSectionsSelected ${LANG_ENGLSH} "You haven't selected any sections!"

LangString MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_A ${LANG_ENGLSH} "Setup will install \
${PRODUCT_NAME} in the following folder..."
LangString MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_B ${LANG_ENGLSH} "Setup will install \
${FLEX_LM} in the following folder..."

;--------------------------------
; Settings
 
!define PROG1_InstDir    "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
!define PROG1_StartIndex ${SEC1}
!define PROG1_EndIndex   ${SEC1}
 
!define PROG2_InstDir "C:\${FLEX_DIR}"
!define PROG2_StartIndex ${SEC3}
!define PROG2_EndIndex   ${SEC3}

;--------------------------------
; Start sections

Section "MyApp" SEC1
  StrCpy $MyAppCheckboxState ${BST_CHECKED}
  ${If} $MyAppCheckboxState == ${BST_CHECKED}
    ##All the files in Group 1 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

    # specify files to go in output path
    File config.dat 
    File MyApp.exe
    File ReleaseNotes.txt
    File MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp
    File MyAppLicense.txt  
  
    # create a shortcut named "new shortcut" in the start menu programs directory
    CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe" 

    # Add application to registry  
    ClearErrors
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Company Name' "${COMPANY_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Version' "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'AppID' "{0be21143-9089-47fa-9736-c45609d13d70}"
 
    # Add program to Add/Remove programs 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayIcon" "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "AppID" "{0be21143-9089-47fa-9736-c45609d13d70}"              
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayName" "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"                 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "InstallLocation" "$INSTDIR"                      
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "Publisher" "${COMPANY_NAME}"                 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "UninstallString" "$\"$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe$\""

    # define uninstaller name
    WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe        

  ${EndIf}

  # messagebox mb_ok sec1
SectionEnd

Section "FlexLM" SEC3
  StrCpy $FlexLmCheckboxState ${BST_CHECKED}
  ${If} $FlexLmCheckboxState == ${BST_CHECKED}    
    ##All the files in Group 2 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

    File installs.exe
    File lmdown.exe
    File lmflex.exe
    
    # define uninstaller name
    WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe

  ${EndIf}    

  # messagebox mb_ok sec3
 
SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Descriptions

  ;Language strings
  LangString DESC_SecMyApp ${LANG_ENGLISH} "MyAppTM software is an easy-to-use suite of tools."
  LangString DESC_SecFlexLM ${LANG_ENGLISH} "FlexSQI contains all the files necessary to implement the FlexLM license server."

  ;Assign language strings to sections
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN    
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC1} $(DESC_SecMyApp)
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC3} $(DESC_SecFlexLM)
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END

Section "Uninstall"  

  # Always delete uninstaller first
  Delete $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe
 
  # now delete installed files and registry keys for MyApp
  Delete $INSTDIR\config.dat
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyApp.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\ReleaseNotes.txt
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyAppLicense.txt
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp.lnk"
  DeleteRegKey HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\Modern UI Test"       
        
  # now delete installed files and registry keys for FlexLM
  Delete $INSTDIR\lmdown.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\lmflex.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\installs.exe

  # Delete the QI Pro and FlexLM directories
  RMDir $INSTDIR

SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
; Please don`t modify below here unless you`re a NSIS 'wiz-kid'
 
## Create $PLUGINSDIR
Function .onInit
  InitPluginsDir

  SetOutPath $TEMP
  File /oname=spltmp.bmp "MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp"

  splash::show 2000 $TEMP\spltmp

  Pop $0 ; $0 has '1' if the user closed the splash screen early,
  ; '0' if everything closed normally, and '-1' if some error occurred.

  Delete $TEMP\spltmp.bmp  
FunctionEnd
        
## If user goes back to this page from 1st Directory page
## we need to put the sections back to how they were before
Var IfBack
Function SelectFilesCheck
  StrCmp $IfBack 1 0 NoCheck
  ;Call ResetFiles
  NoCheck:
FunctionEnd
 
## Also if no sections are selected, warn the user!
Function ComponentsLeave
Push $R0
Push $R1
 
 Call IsPROG1Selected
  Pop $R0
 Call IsPROG2Selected
  Pop $R1
 StrCmp $R0 1 End
 StrCmp $R1 1 End
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
 MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "$(NoSectionsSelected)"
 Abort
 
End:
Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
    
Function IsPROG1Selected
Push $R0

 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG1_StartIndex} # Group 1 start
 
   SectionGetFlags 0 $R0            # Get section flags
    IntOp $R0 $R0 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    StrCmp $R0 ${SF_SELECTED} 0 +3      # If section is selected, done
     StrCpy $R0 1
 
Exch $R0
FunctionEnd
 
Function IsPROG2Selected
Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R1 ${PROG2_StartIndex}    # Group 2 start
 
   IntOp $R1 $R1 + 1
   SectionGetFlags 1 $R1            # Get section flags
    IntOp $R1 $R1 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    StrCmp $R1 ${SF_SELECTED} 0 +3      # If section is selected, done
     StrCpy $R1 1
 
Exch $R1
FunctionEnd

## Here we are selecting first sections to install
## by unselecting all the others!
Function SelectFilesA
 
 # If user clicks Back now, we will know to reselect Group 2`s sections for
 # Components page
 StrCpy $IfBack 1
 
 # We need to save the state of the Group 2 Sections
 # for the next InstFiles page
Push $R0
Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG2_StartIndex} # Group 2 start
 
;  Loop:
;   IntOp $R0 $R0 + 1
;   SectionGetFlags $R0 $R1                 # Get section flags
;    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\sections.ini" Sections $R0 $R1 # Save state
;    !insertmacro UnselectSection $R0               # Then unselect it
;    StrCmp $R0 ${PROG2_EndIndex} 0 Loop
 
 # Don`t install prog 1?
 Call IsPROG1Selected
 Pop $R0
 StrCmp $R0 1 +4
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
  Abort
 
 # Set current $INSTDIR to PROG1_InstDir define
 StrCpy $INSTDIR "${PROG1_InstDir}"
 
Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
 
## Here we need to unselect all Group 1 sections
## and then re-select those in Group 2 (that the user had selected on
## Components page)
Function SelectFilesB
Push $R0
;Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG1_StartIndex}    # Group 1 start
 
;  Loop:
;   IntOp $R0 $R0 + 1
;    !insertmacro UnselectSection $R0       # Unselect it
;    StrCmp $R0 ${PROG1_EndIndex} 0 Loop
 
; Call ResetFiles
 
 # Don't install prog 2?
 Call IsPROG2Selected
 Pop $R0
 StrCmp $R0 1 +4
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
  Abort
 
 # Set current $INSTDIR to PROG2_InstDir define
 StrCpy $INSTDIR "${PROG2_InstDir}"
 
;Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
## Here we are deleting the temp INI file at the end of installation
Function DeleteSectionsINI
 FlushINI "$PLUGINSDIR\Sections.ini"
 Delete "$PLUGINSDIR\Sections.ini"
FunctionEnd
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

Please note that I think the issue might be in this file:

```
~\NSIS\Contrib\Modern UI 2\Pages\Directory.nsh
```

Where I see this code:

```
!macro MUI_FUNCTION_DIRECTORYPAGE PRE SHOW LEAVE

  Function "${PRE}"
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FUNCTION_CUSTOM PRE
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT_PAGE $(MUI_${MUI_PAGE_UNINSTALLER_PREFIX}TEXT_DIRECTORY_TITLE) $(MUI_${MUI_PAGE_UNINSTALLER_PREFIX}TEXT_DIRECTORY_SUBTITLE)
  FunctionEnd

  Function "${SHOW}"
  
    ;Get control handles
    FindWindow $mui.DirectoryPage "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.Text $mui.DirectoryPage 1006
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.DirectoryBox $mui.DirectoryPage 1020
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.Directory $mui.DirectoryPage 1019
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.BrowseButton $mui.DirectoryPage 1001
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.SpaceRequired $mui.DirectoryPage 1023
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.SpaceAvailable $mui.DirectoryPage 1024
  
    !ifdef MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_BGCOLOR
      !insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXTCOLOR ""
      SetCtlColors $mui.DirectoryPage.Directory "${MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXTCOLOR}" "${MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_BGCOLOR}"
    !endif
    
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FUNCTION_CUSTOM SHOW
  FunctionEnd

  Function "${LEAVE}"
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FUNCTION_CUSTOM LEAVE
  FunctionEnd

!macroend
```

But when I look at the above it still is not clear to me how the MyApp name could be added to the end of the directory string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here:

[NSIS Directory Page after Browse for install dir "${PRODUCT_NAME}" is added after selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254050/nsis-directory-page-after-browse-for-install-dir-product-name-is-added-afte?rq=1)

So in my case I needed to add a :

```
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\"
```